# How to test XML Queue with Cucumber Code?

Tags: java, cucumber, jms

Any sample cucumber code where I can submit an xml message in a queue and data being read and processed?

Comment: What queue, what xml message, what are you looking at?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book></catalog>

Comment: When I dump the above message in a MQ Queue something like MD.BookQueue.v1.Sub. System processes the message.